# How to access Array elements as constants - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to store the Color values in Java Array but I know that these values are stored as strings,

```
String[] colorarray = {"Color.yellow","Color.red","Color.blue"};
```

Now, I couldn't access this array element to set the color, i.e

```
g.setColor(colorarray[0]);
```

Because all the values in the array are strings.
How could I convert these values to the constants ?

Comment: Maybe an `enum` would be a better fit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over the array, by all means change it to just be an array of `Color`s as suggested by several other people.

```
Color[] colorArray = {Color.YELLOW, Color.RED, Color.BLUE};
```

If you don't have control over the array and you have to use it as-is, you'll need to do one of two things:

1. Use reflection to access the static members of the `Color` class
   (a quick Google search will give you plenty of examples on how to do this so I won't go into it here)
2. Create a Java 7 switch statement on the Strings to interpret each possible color value in the array into `Color.XXX` where `XXX` is the name of your color. (This could also be done using a big if-else block but that wouldn't be as clean)

One other quick note - variable names in Java are, by convention, in camelCase starting with a lower-case letter.  This helps make your code more readable.  (Class names are CamelCase, package names are lower.case)

Comment: Note that the switch-on-strings solution is pretty cumbersome, which is why I listed it second.  Reflection would be better.

Comment: Correction: It would be better assuming the performance overhead of using reflection isn't an obstacle for your application.  That's something only you can weigh

Answer (score 11):

Use

```
Color[] colorArray = {Color.YELLOW, Color.RED, Color.BLUE};
```

Comment: I didn't downvote (and won't) but you do assume that he has control over the array

Comment: Reflection is definitely something which I would try and steer away from especially given its performance cost/complexity vs. a simple array lookup

Comment: @Reimus there are definitely pros and cons.  The performance cost is only a con though if the application is getting fairly heavy use.  The question boils down to weighing whether the extra code to translate from strings to `Color.XXX` via switch is going to be enough of a performance gain to justify cluttering your code.  I'm guessing from the fact that he accepted my answer over yours that he doesn't have control of how the array is coming to him, though I don't really know

Comment: For the record, assuming he DOES have control over the array, I agree with you that a `Color[]` array is a far better solution

Answer (score 7):

Straightforward, use this :

```
Color[] colorarray = {Color.YELLOW, Color.RED, Color.BLUE};
```